# no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream' and '')

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm programing a phonebook and there is something wrong in reading from the file.
      the error is: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream' and '') [on hold]

this function is for write in a txt file:

```
   void PhoneBook::Save(){  while(1)
 {
 ofstream file;
 file.open("test.txt",ios::app);
        file<<contact.first<<endl 
              <<contact.last<<endl
              <<contact.areacode<<endl 
              <<contact.number<<endl
              <<contact.email<<endl
              <<contact.webaddr<<endl 
              <<contact.address;

    }}
```

and load function is:

```
void PhoneBook::Load()
{
    ifstream file("test.txt");
                                //how i can make it(reading from file)correct?
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file>>contact.first>>endl     
            >>contact.last>>endl     
                  >>contact.areacode>>endl 
                  >>contact.number>>endl
                  >>contact.email>>endl
                  >>contact.webaddr>>endl 
                  >>contact.address;
    }
    else
        cout<<"error in openening file";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bo said, `std::endl` is for output, not for input. What you really want to use is `std::getline(std::istream, std::string &)`. Use it like this:

```
std::getline(file, contact.first);
std::getline(file, contact.last);
std::getline(file, contact.the_rest_of_the_strings_in_contact);
```

This will instead read until the newline character (which looks like what you want).

Answer (score 3):

`std::endl` is used for output, not for input.

And `operator>>` will skip newline anyway, along with any other white space it sees in the input.